# How can I dynamically populate a table in Google Doc using their API?

Tags: python, google-docs, google-docs-api

In Python, I have a list of dicts with all the data I want to display inside a table in a Google Doc:

```py
fruits = [
    {"name": "apple", "description":"juicy", "stuff": "why not?"},
    {"name": "banana", "description":"healthy", "stuff": "yeah!"},
    ...
]
```

Each item in the `fruits` list correspond to a row in the table I want to populate. Each value inside theses items is a new cell on that row.

Now, I have a Google Doc I use as a template. There's an empty table in it:
[image]

I want to dynamically populate that table with the previous `fruits` list in my Python code.

This is my code so far:

```py
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
CREDENTIALS = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(os.environ["CREDS"], scopes=SCOPES)
GOOGLE_DOCS_SERVICE = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=CREDENTIALS)


def get_table_requests(fruits):
    requests = []
    # We create new rows in the selected table
    # This part works !
    for i in range(0, len(fruits) - 1):
        requests.append(
            {
                "insertTableRow": {
                    "tableCellLocation": {
                        "tableStartLocation": {"index": 2488},
                        "rowIndex": 1,
                        "columnIndex": 1,
                    },
                    "insertBelow": "true",
                }
            }
        )

    # We insert the text into the table cells using the insertText object.
    # This part does NOT work !
    index = 2580  # set index to first empty cell
    for fruit in fruits:
        for _, value in fruit.items():
            value += "\n"
            requests.append({"insertText": {"location": {"index": index}, "text": str(value)}})
            index += len(str(value)) + 2  # set index to next cell
        index += 1  # set index to new row

    return requests


def modify_document(new_doc_id):
    template_result = GOOGLE_DOCS_SERVICE.documents().get(documentId=TEMPLATE_FILE_ID).execute()

    fruits = [
        {"name": "apple", "description":"juicy", "stuff": "why not?"},
        {"name": "banana", "description":"healthy", "stuff": "yeah!"}
    ]

    requests = get_table_requests(fruits)


    GOOGLE_DOCS_SERVICE.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=new_doc_id,
                                                         body={'requests': requests}).execute()
```

The first part (`insertTableRow`) works : rows are created. But the second part (`insertText`) fails, even with the right index.
I get this error:

```bash
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError:
<HttpError 400 when requesting https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/some_id:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid requests[6].insertText: The insertion index must be inside the bounds of an existing paragraph. You can still create new paragraphs by inserting newlines.".
Details: "Invalid requests[6].insertText: The insertion index must be inside the bounds of an existing paragraph. You can still create new paragraphs by inserting newlines.">
```

I don't really understand this error. I tried to add some newlines but doesnt work.

Comment: I think that in your current issue of `Invalid requests[6].insertText: The insertion index must be inside the bounds of an existing paragraph. You can still create new paragraphs by inserting newlines.`, it is required to correctly replicate it. So, in order to correctly replicate your current issue, can you provide the sample Document of `new_doc_id`? And, in your script, it seems that `template_result` is not used. Is this related to your expected result?

Comment: @Tanaike I created a new doc for testing purposes if you wanna try, the ID is : 1VpVJ_fgDigv0AFxsNUg5A10jpdW2yOvMK8OVyMAAR5U. I think it does not work because the table I want to populate is not the first one in the document. I get various errors : the same as before and Invalid table start location.

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing your sample Document. I think that your sample Document is your sample input situation. If my understanding is correct, can you provide your sample output situation you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for your time! Here's the output of the test Google Doc I created : https://gist.github.com/cuzureau/bfaf4f533133a439c52fefd6abc73f67

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you provide the Google Document of your expected result using your sample input Document? First, I would like to correctly understand your question. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 1):

### *SUGGESTION*

I did my own investigation & here are the things I have observed:

- It looks like the table row should be created first before the insert text request to work properly.
- Running all of the requests (`insertTableRow` & `insertText`) in one `batchUpdate` call seems to not work when you are **dynamically** adding table rows & text data per cell.

**Perhaps you can try reviewing this quick test script below. Here's the overview of this script:**

1. Find the `endIndex` on the table & set it as the starting index. *(On my sample docs file, it is index 45)*
2. Insert a table row for each `Fruits` values per loop iteration.
3. Once  a row gets inserted, insert the current fruit values with the current index.
4. Once all of the current text values have been inserted, add 1 to the very last index as it'll be the next starting index for the next table row that will be inserted.
5. Repeat #2.

> Note: I have used `Google Colaboratory` to do this replication & kindly disregard the authentication part of the code as it is different from your Python setup.

### Python script

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import json


#Authentication [NOTE:] I have a different Python setup
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '/content/CREDS.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

# Build the services
GOOGLE_DOCS_SERVICE = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)

# Retrieve the documents contents from the Docs service.
document = GOOGLE_DOCS_SERVICE.documents().get(documentId=DOCS_ID).execute()

#Find the the end index from the table & set as the starting index
index = document['body']['content'][3]['endIndex'];

#Starting table row index
rowInx = 1;

#The values
fruits =  [
        {"name": "apple", "description":"juicy", "stuff": "why not?"},
        {"name": "banana", "description":"healthy", "stuff": "yeah!"},
        {"name": "papaya", "description":"another healthy", "stuff": "want"}
    ]

for fruit in fruits:
  #Append a table row for each fruit index values
  request1 = [{'insertTableRow': {'tableCellLocation': {'tableStartLocation': {'index': 2},'rowIndex': rowInx,'columnIndex': 1},'insertBelow': 'true'}}]
  GOOGLE_DOCS_SERVICE.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=DOCS_ID, body={'requests': request1}).execute()
  #Increment the table row index for the next fruit values
  rowInx += 1
  for x in fruit.values():
    print(index,x)
    #Insert the values of each fruit on the current table row
    request2 = [{'insertText': {'location': {'index': index},'text': x}}]
    GOOGLE_DOCS_SERVICE.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=DOCS_ID, body={'requests': request2}).execute()
    #Set the index for the next values
    index = index + (len(str(x))+ 2)
  index += 1;
```

### Demo:

- *After running the script:*

[image]

- *Sample Google Docs file used:*

[image]

- *Sample log result for review:*

[image]

Comment: Very detailed answer! I understand your logic but when I try to apply this to my specific google doc, it does not work. I created a new doc for testing purposes if you wanna try, the ID is : `1VpVJ_fgDigv0AFxsNUg5A10jpdW2yOvMK8OVyMAAR5U`.  I think it does not work because the table I want to populate is not the first one in the document. I get various errors : the same as before and `Invalid table start location.`

Comment: i had the same problem, fixed with "{"index": index + 1}" instead of "{"index": index}" in the request2